# Can't run postgres on my system. It's showing `postgres is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.`

Tags: postgresql, sudo, su

I'm trying to install postgres on my WSL Ubuntu. Installation is finished but when I run `psql` the following error is displayed.

`psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory`
`Is the server running locally and accepting`
`connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

And when I run `sudo find /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` to find the file, it's showing another error like this.

`postgres is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

It'll be more clear from the screenshot.

How to continue? Please help...

**Screenshot:**

[image: reference]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This error seems to be because your username, i.e `postgres` is not in the sudoers file. Which is why you don't have authority to run the above command for the `postgres` user.

Try adding the user by:

Open file

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
```

Then add the user below admin user like below syntax.

```
user_name ALL=(ALL)  ALL
```

Comment: The proper mechanism on Debian-based distros is `sudo adduser yourself sudoers` but of course if you aren't in `sudoers` you can't `sudo` anything.

Comment: Thanks! It worked... Also the postgres cluster status was down. After adding postgres to the sudoers file I've restarted postgres by using this. #format is pg_ctlcluster <version> <cluster> <action>
sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.6 main start

#restart PostgreSQL service
sudo service postgresql restart

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)